# Multiple events with Drag and Drop inside my ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

I have simple `WPF` application with `ListView`.

i added the option to add files into my `ListView` via `Drag`:

```
ListView lv;

private void lv_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void lv_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(files[0]);
        AddFiles(files);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}

private void AddFiles(string[] files)
{
   // Add the files into my `ListView`.
}
```

The problem is that after `Drag` one file into my `ListView` trigger the event more than several times so the same files added into the list several times.
What could happen this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the DragEnter event. This event "Occurs when an object is dragged into the control's bounds."
See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you're looking for is the DragDrop-Event which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3).

Comment: There is no DragDrop event in my ListView.

Comment: Okay sorry, take a look at this: https://fxmax.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/wpf/ your listview needs a drop attribute on which you bind a method to handle the event